# Consulta eloquent dos tablas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una tabla de productos que tiene los campos:

> id, nombre, precio, id_categoria

Y tengo la tabla de categoria con los campos:

> id, nombre

Estoy intentado hacer que devuelva todos los campos de la tabla productos y en lugar de mostrarme el id me muestre el nombre de la categoria.
Sabria hacerlo con SQL pero no con eloquent.

EDIT:
La finalidad es devolver un json con todos los datos de los productos y el id categoria substituido con el nombre, ya que se trata de una API con laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> puedes en el modelo `Categoria` (asumiendo que asi se llame), crear el
>   siguiente método

En este primero ocupamos la relación `hasMany()` por que se entiende que una categoría tiene asociados a ella muchos productos

```
public function productos()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Producto::class);
}
```

Es obvio que tendrás que poner donde yo coloque `Producto::class` el nombre que tu le diste a tu modelo donde manejas la tabla productos

Posterior en el modelo `Producto`, hacer lo siguiente

En esta parte hago uso de la relación `belongsTo()` por que se entiende que un producto pertenece a una categoria

```
public function categoria()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class);
}
```

> Explico.

Para acceder a dichos valores, en la vista se hace lo siguiente

```
@foreach($productos as $producto)
    {{ $producto->nombre }}
    {{ $producto->precio }}
    {{ $producto->find($producto->id)->categoria->name}}

@endforeach
```

Ojo el `categoria->name`, se refiere al método `categoria` y a la tabla `categoria` y a la columna `name` de esa tabla

Aquí la fuente de consulta oficial, la documentación de Laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Me parece muy interesante esta forma, el caso es que estoy haciendo una api que al llamar a una funcion determinada devuelve un json con todos los datos de la tabla productos, para luego tratarlo con react, y no usaria las vistas de laravel, habria alguna forma de hacerlo desde el controlador?

Comment: entonces aclara eso en tu pregunta, pues como esta redactada es muy amplia entonces

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente lo he conseguido asi

```
$products = Productos::join('Categorias','idCategoria', '=', 'Categorias.id')->select('Productos.id','Productos.nombre','Categorias.nombre as NombreCategoria')->get();
```

Aunque no he conseguido entender muy bien como usar 'belongsto' y 'hasmany' para hacer esta consulta...

EDIT:
Finalmente basandome un poco en la respuesta de Alfredo he conseguido que lo muestre
Añadiendo esto al modelo de productos:

```
public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class, 'idCategoria');
    }
```

Y llamadolo asi desde el metodo del controlador:

```
public function index_front() {
        $products = Productos::with('categoria')->get();
        return json_encode($products);
    }
```

El unico problema es que me muestra todos los datos de categoria dentro de un array en la respuesta y yo solo queria el nombre...

Comment: Prueba usar el método pluck para extraer sólo los datos que quieres ejemplo: `Productos::with('categoria')->pluck('nombre')->get();`

Comment: Estoy intentado esto "Productos::with('categoria')->pluck('categoria.nombre')->get();" pero me salta error que no existe la columna en la fila.

Comment: Según tu select deberías usar 'NombreCategoria'

Comment: NombreCategoria es el alias que le puse a ese field para acceder a el.

Comment: Me parece interesante, quisiera saber si puedo hacer en un modelo que vaya a verificar 2 tablas distintas (que no tienen relacion) al mismo tiempo. yo se que esto se formulo hace mucho tiempo pero a ese tiempo ni siquiera sabia de laravel. jajaja